# Complex Django query over foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models in the same application. The application is called "News", and it has two classes in its model called "Article" and "Category".

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=100, unique=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_("Category"))
    archived = models.BooleanField(_("Archive this?"), default=False)
```

I want to create a query that shows me all of the articles which are archived but grouped by category.

How would I accomplish this efficiently?

Comment: please don't tell me it's as simple as this:
   >>> c = Category.objects.filter(article__archived=True)

Comment: see my answer so i can see exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > > c = Category.objects.filter(article__archived=True)

Answer (score 3):

```
Article.objects.filter(archived=True).order_by('category')
```

i am editing this to get more info to try and help out.

given:

- cat1

  - art1
  - art2-archived
  - art3
- cat2

  - art4
  - art5
  - art6-archived
- cat3

  - art7-archived
  - art8-archived
  - art9

what would you want your queryset to contain?

Comment: actually Category.objects.filter(article__archived=True) works.

Comment: @blackrobot: but you said you wanted `Articles`. Your query (assuming it works, I haven't tested it) will return `Categorys` that contain archived `Articles`. Brandon H's query will return a list of `Articles` ordered by `Category`.

Comment: Yeah, i wanted "grouped by category".

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this what you want?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='articles')
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

categories = Category.objects.select_related("articles").filter(articles__archived=True)
```